# Are both your nose and forehead supposed to rest on the turbah during sujood?

Tags: salat, shiism, sajda

When praying with [turbah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbah), I understand we place our forehead on it during sujood (as per [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/934/17163)), but I'm unsure of where to place my nose.

> One instance is the tradition Ibn Abbas narrates from the Prophet (a.s):  [Arabic omitted]  The prayer of one, who doesn’t put his nose on the same thing as he puts his forehead, would not be accepted.  -- [Al Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/shiism-sunnism-ayatullah-sayyid-muhammad-ridha-mudarrisi-yazdi/prostration-tradition-prophet-and)

So it looks like we should place our noses on turbah too.  However, some of the stones I've seen are very small, too small to reach from one's forehead to the tip of their nose.  This puzzles me.

**Question**: Are both your nose and forehead supposed to rest on the turbah during sujood?

Comment: It is recommended to place your nose on the turbah too. Therefore some people use two turbah  as even with the bigger ones it is not possible to touch forehead and nose. This is a recommendation. It's sufficient to place the forehead on turbah and nose touches the prayer mat.

Comment: About your significant/applicable question, Noor's comment seems true/helpful as mentioned: It is recommended to place your nose on the turbah too (as a recommendation)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both nose and forehead should touch the turbah. While touching the forehead should not be covered by any cloth (cap, scarf, etc.) or any other thing. The skin of the forehead should touch the turbah. It is only allowed when the forehead is injured and it is bandaged or any other such circumstances.

Other than that the weight of your body should be on the forehead, just a slight touch is not allowed. It is the sharth of Salat, so if it is not done correctly, the Salat will be broken.

*P.S. My answer is according to Shafa'i mazhab*

Answer (score -1):

The Shia view is: You don't even need a turbah. Using Turbah is just recommended (*مستحب*). Using another for nose is just *another* recommended act.

Majority of Shia scholars agree that it's wajib to pray on something clean like: Rocks, Marble, Paper or turbah which is the best. You can't do sajda on gold, silver, anything edible or something used in clothes.

The best of turbas are the cleanest ones, from pure lands. To Shia the cleanest ones are those that have the blood of Prophet Muhammad grandson's *blood* or just come from a holy city.